# Get valid getSystemCpuLoad()

Tags: java, cpu-usage

I am using jdk7. I am trying to get the Total CPU usage through this statement

```
System.out.println("getCpuUsage()" + " = " + operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad());
```

The values I am getting is like

```
0.012323
0.054544
0.0234243
etc..
```

The CPU usage in task manager I see is like 5%, 10%, 60%,etc. How can I get the value like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to multiply it by 100 and convert to integer, look at the JavaDocs :

> Returns the "recent cpu usage" for the whole system. This value is a
>   double in the [0.0,1.0] interval. A value of 0.0 means that all CPUs
>   were idle during the recent period of time observed, while a value of
>   1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running 100% of the time during the recent period being observed. All values betweens 0.0 and 1.0 are
>   possible depending of the activities going on in the system. If the
>   system recent cpu usage is not available, the method returns a
>   negative value.

*Be careful about the number of CPU you have on your system, since it is representative of all the CPU available on your system .*

Take a look at this helper method to scale the value you get to percentage :

```
 public static short getLoadAndScaleToPercent(Method method, OperatingSystemMXBean osMxBean) {
        if (method != null) {
            try {
                double load = (double) method.invoke(osMxBean);
                if (load >= 0) {
                    return (short) (load * 100);
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just multiply with 100. You will get result as a percentage. Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad()) for javadoc.